# How do you pluralize the first letter of acronym?

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-number, acronyms, initialisms

How does one pluarlize an acronym (or initialism) when the first letter of the acronym is the one to be pluarlized?
What acronym is to be used for "*way**s** of reasoning*" if WoR is "*way of reasoning*"?

Comment: Once you've turned it into an acronym or initialism it's pronounced "double you oh are" or "Wore" and the plural is "double you oh ares" or "wores"

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate: [Pluralizing abbreviations where the noun is not the last word](//english.stackexchange.com/q/334097/26083).

Answer (score 4):

From the Wikipedia page [Acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym).

> A particularly rich source of options arises when the plural of an acronym would normally be indicated in a word other than the final word if spelled out in full. A classic example is Member of Parliament, which in plural is Members of Parliament. It is possible then to abbreviate this as M's P. (or similar), as used by former Australian Prime Minister Ben Chifley. This usage is less common than forms with s at the end, such as MPs, and may appear dated or pedantic. In common usage, therefore, weapons of mass destruction becomes WMDs, prisoners of war becomes POWs, and runs batted in becomes RBIs.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. Don't forget to take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers when you stick around.